# Java deserialize JSON where a variable is named "class"

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I am currently deserializing JSON data on a Java application, using Gson.
The thing is that there is a variable named `class`, but Java doesn't let me define a variable named this way in my object (the object where the Json will be stored into).

```
public class InfosHistory {
    String title;
    String user;
    String content;
    String date;
    String id;
    String visible;
    String id_activite;
    String class; <--
}
```

Comment: You know you can deserialize the object manually with GSON? You don't have to have it do it automatically.

Comment: Could you explain more ? I'm using retrofit, with a Gson converter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [attributes](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-annotations-example/) to define the serialized name:

```
public class InfosHistory {
    String title;
    String user;
    String content;
    String date;
    String id;
    String visible;
    String id_activite;

    @SerializedName("class")
    String class_name;
}
```